# How can I improve my Image comparison Algorithm

Tags: image, algorithm, image-processing, graphics

I want to compare an image with a set of more than 1000 images. I am generating a photomosaic.

What I have done so far:

I am using the LAB color model to get the L A B value of each image and stored this value in a KD-tree. 
This is a 3 dimensional tree with L A* B* values. Then I calculate the LAB value for each grid in an image for which I have to generate the photomosaic. I use the Nearest Neighbor Algorithm and Euclidean distance metric to find the best match.

I am getting a good result but I want to improve my result. I read about SIFT for image comparison, it looks interesting and I will be implementing it in the future. For now can you guys suggest any other features I could compare like brightness, background color or may be another distance metric which is better than Euclidean ?

Comment: One easy way to get "better results" is just to linearly mix your scaled source image with each of your little photomosaic components. When you look at each individual photomosaic image, you can't really tell that the colour has been adjusted, but the overall effect is much better.

Comment: How are you evaluating your result?  It's hard for us to suggest something that's "better" without knowing what you definition of "good" is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appart from SIFT, another feature that has been used is to compare color histograms through the Earth Movers' Distance. You can look at papers such as :
[The earth mover's distance as a metric for image retrieval](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~tomasi/papers/rubner/rubnerTr98.pdf)

Also, more similar to SIFT is the GIST of an image, that has been used for "semantic" (more or less) retrieval :
[Building the gist of a scene: the role of global image
features in recognition](http://cvcl.mit.edu/papers/olivatorralbapbr2006.pdf)
which has been used for instance in the paper that does scene completion using millions of photographs:
[Scene Completion Using Millions of Photographs](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/projects/scene-completion/)

You can also adapt the methods that use SIFT for image warping (for instance [SIFT Flow: Dense Correspondence across Scenes and its Applications](http://people.csail.mit.edu/celiu/SIFTflow/SIFTflow.pdf)) to derive a metric for image comparison. Often, standard SIFT matching perform poorly and your resulting metric is not great : being able to have a good matching will make things better.

In short, as a comment said, it depends what you are trying to compare and achieve (what do you mean by "good") : do you want to match colors (Histograms) ? structure (SIFT) ? semantics (GIST) ? or else ...?